What should I do if "The repository ppa.launchpadcontent.net doesn't have a Release file" && no sound?
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
So, what should I do? Also, after the latest ubuntu update my built-in-audio, speakers of my laptop suddenly stopped working, but if I choose something different, for example my HDMI Monitor, then everything works correctly.
I have ubuntu 22.04, Asus Rog Strix G512LU, corei7, nvidia.
For reference I also couldn't change the volume, it is always max or none. But I found out that this is only the problem with the motherboard of the ROG laptops and there is no solution, but if you can solve that, would be great!

We don't keep track of the "latest ubuntu update" from PPAs, so package version numbers would be very helpful. You should report the problem to the PPA author. You could also test your audio hardware with a 24.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment -- maybe the PPA is unnecessary.

A quick look at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily shows there is no support for any release later than 19.04 as that PPA is no longer used (isn't used by any supported release)

@guiverc thanks a lot, but what should I do now if it is not supported, how I can change the ppa, any resources maybe that can be helpful

PPAs are 3rd party repositories; so the only checks on them are those you perform yourself. Did you perform any?  (ie. is is still maintained? developer(s) can be trusted? has support for your release/use-case? etc  FYI:  The URL I provided was taken from your question)  That PPA will do you no good, so just remove it (reverse procedure for however you added it; there are many ways you can do that though).
